# Moq return type IEnumerable being returned as List

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, moq

I am having trouble getting Moq to return `IEnumerable` types from repository methods.

**Update - 1**

I was hoping that I was just missing something but, as requested, here is the full implementation that is in place.

Asserting that the `objResult.Value` is of type `IEnumerable<ListItemDTO>` is what is failing.

**Repository interface**

```
public interface IRepository
{
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetListAsync<T>(string storedProcedure, object template);

    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetListAsync<T>(string sql, CommandType commandType, object template);
}

public interface ICRUDRepository<TEntity>
{
    Task<TEntity> GetByIdAsync(long Id);

    Task<int> AddAsync(TEntity entity);

    Task<int> UpdateAsync(TEntity entity);

    Task<int> DeleteAsync(long id);
}

public interface ITARRepository : IRepository, ICRUDRepository<TARTracker>
{
    Task<IEnumerable<TARTrackerDate>> GetTARTrackerApprovedDates(long tarTrackerId);
    Task<IEnumerable<TARTrackerDate>> MergeTARApprovalDateChanges(DataTable approvedDates);
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class TARTrackerController : Controller
{
    private readonly ITARRepository Repository;
    private readonly ILogger<TARTrackerController> Logger;

    public TARTrackerController(ILogger<TARTrackerController> logger, ITARRepository repository) 
    {
        Repository = repository;
        Logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet("TARTrackers")]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, typeof(IEnumerable<ListItemDTO>))]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, null)]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, null)]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable, null)]
    [Description("Get TAR Tracker List")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(long accountId)
    {
        try
        {
            var trackers = await Repository.GetListAsync<ListItemDTO>("spFDBGetAccountTARList", new { @ParamAccountID = accountId });

            return Ok(trackers);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.LogError(LogEvents.Services, e, $"An error occured in {0}.{1}", nameof(TARTrackerController), nameof(Get));

            return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
    }
}
```

Unit test:

```
public class TARTrackerControllerTests
{
    public static ILogger<TARTrackerController> Logger = Mock.Of<ILogger<TARTrackerController>>();
    public static Mock<ITARRepository> Repository = new Mock<ITARRepository>();

    public class GetTARTrackersTests
    {
        [Fct]
        public async Task Returns_OK_With_ListItemDTO()
        {
            //arrange
            var id = 12345;
            IEnumerable<ListItemDTO> expected = new List<ListItemDTO>();

            Repository
                .Setup(repo => repo.GetListAsync<ListItemDTO>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>()))
                .ReturnsAsync(expected);

            var controller = new TARTrackerController(Logger, Repository.Object);

            //act
            var result = await controller.Get(id);

            //assert
            var objResult = Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(result);
            Assert.Equal(typeof(IEnumerable<ListItemDTO>), objResult.Value.GetType());
        }
    }
}
```

I feel like this should match. Can't seem to figure out what is going on. Any help?

Comment: Have you tried `expected.AsEnumerable()`?

Comment: @MuhammadHannan yeah, it still returns `List<T>`.

Comment: @dbarth What is actually happening as apposed to what you expect to happen.

Comment: @dbarth It would be awesome if you could share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the unit test that can be used to reproduce the problem. What is shown so far should work, but with a complete picture of what is being tested and actually happening, we are left guessing the problem.

Comment: I suspect that you expect `expected.GetType()` to return `IEnumerable` - could you please [edit] post to clarify whether it is the case or now (as well updating sample code + expected result as @Nkosi suggested)

Comment: @Nkosi I've updated the implementation and what is being returned by the repository is unclear when I try to debug the test. However, when it get's returned by the controller it is a type of `List<ListItemDTO>`.

Comment: Do you really care what is the type of actual value? What you care about is that returned value can be enumerated and contain expected values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it seems only the assertion was wrong which was the general consensus here but, it actually should be accomplished in the following manner.

```
Assert.IsAssignableFrom<IEnumerable<ListItemDTO>>(objResult.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a spelling mistake in `IEnumerable` in what you show as the controller code, which suggests it's not the code you really use. This may or may not mean the mistake is not related to the test code.

I'm not sure where the problem in your code is but here is a passing test.

```
public class ListItemDTO { public string Name { get; set; } }

public interface IRepo
{
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetListAsync<T>(string storedProcedure, object template);
}

public class Ctrl
{
    private readonly IRepo repo;
    public Ctrl(IRepo repo) { this.repo = repo; }

    // BTW. Check out IAsyncEnumerable<T> 
    public async Task<IEnumerable<ListItemDTO>> GetAync()
        => await repo.GetListAsync<ListItemDTO>("spGetAccountList", new { @ParamAccountID = 1 });
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Test1()
    {
        var mockRepo = new Mock<IRepo>(MockBehavior.Strict);

        IEnumerable<ListItemDTO> expected = new List<ListItemDTO>() { new ListItemDTO { Name = "Prince" } };

        mockRepo.Setup(repo => repo.GetListAsync<ListItemDTO>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>()))
                .ReturnsAsync(expected);

        var tested = new Ctrl(repo: mockRepo.Object);

        var actual = await tested.GetAync();

        Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, actual.Count(), "Expecting exactly one item");
        var first = actual.First();
        Assert.AreEqual("Prince", first.Name, "Checking 1st item's 'Name'");
    }
}
```

The library setup is as follows:

```
<package id="Moq" version="4.13.1" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="MSTest.TestAdapter" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="MSTest.TestFramework" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Replacing

`IEnumerable<ListItemDTO> expected = new List<ListItemDTO>();`

with

`IEnumerable<ListItemDTO> expected = Enumerable.Empty<ListItemDTO>`

should work.

However, I'm not sure that this is a problem in any case; because `List<T>` [already is an implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8) of `IEnumerable<T>`, so from a "typing" perspective, it's quite OK; and any check you wanted to do on the contents of the returned data, etc, will work just as well if the type is `List<T>` as if it's `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: @tymtam - because it returns an `IEnumerable<T>` which would be an exact type match. Bear in mind that the question as originally posed doesn't really make it clear what the problem is (no details of failing assert on the test, etc) so was making a little bit of a shot in the dark with the above answer.